# Fortran 90 with C/C++ style macro (e.g. # define SUBNAME(x) s ## x)

Tags: macros, preprocessor, fortran90, gfortran

I am recently working with a F90 code project. I am using gfortran (linux and MinGW) to compile it. There is something interesting in file loct.F90.

```
#  define TYPE real(4)
#  define SUBNAME(x) s ## x
#  include "loct_inc.F90"
#  undef SUBNAME
#  undef TYPE

#  define TYPE real(8)
#  define SUBNAME(x) d ## x
#  include "loct_inc.F90"
#  undef SUBNAME
#  undef TYPE
...
```

The loct_inc.F90 file looks like this:

```
subroutine SUBNAME(loct_pointer_copy_1)(o, i)
...
end subroutine SUBNAME(loct_pointer_copy_1)


subroutine SUBNAME(loct_pointer_copy_2)(o, i)
...
end subroutine SUBNAME(loct_pointer_copy_2)


...
```

I think in the file loct.F90 the author used sets of macros (C/C++ style). Each set is used to define a data type (e.g. real(4), real(8), character, etc). The file loct_inc.F90 provide a set of function which is the same except the type of the variables.
These two files works together as a template of c++ in my opinion.

In the end one should have a set of subroutines:

```
sloct_pointer_copy_1(o, i)
sloct_pointer_copy_2(o, i)
...

dloct_pointer_copy_1(o, i)
dloct_pointer_copy_2(o, i)
...
```

But when I tried to compile loct.F90 (gfortran -c loct.F90), I get some errors.

> basic/loct_inc.F90:21.13:
>       Included at basic/loct.F90:256:
>
> subroutine s ## loct_pointer_copy_1(o, i)
>                1 Error: Syntax error in SUBROUTINE statement at (1)

It seems gfortran replace SUBNAME(loct_pointer_copy_1)(o, i) with s ## loct_pointer_copy_1(o, i). But according to c++ macro, the correct replace should be sloct_pointer_copy_1(o, i).

Could anyone tell me why this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU Fortran uses the GNU C Preprocessor in *traditional mode*, in which mode the macro pasting operator `##` is not available. That's why Fortran projects which were written to also compile with the GNU toolchain perform explicit preprocessing in additional Makefile targets, e.g. all `*.F90` are first preprocessed with `cpp` to temporary `.f90` files which are then compiled.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hristo. I'll preprocess f90 files first. I'll search for a while to see if I can find a answer.